# Macbook pro not booting after multiple reinstalls

Tags: boot, 22.04, macbook

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my MacBook Pro (Mid-2012, 15 inch), but my computer won't boot. Here's what my screen looks like when I try to power on my machine.
[image: Errors]
I keep getting these errors even after wiping my macOS partition and doing a clean install. Any ideas?

EDIT: I got my system to boot by reinstalling Ubuntu without installing drivers and updates. It seems that other people have similar problems as me. I'm going to install each driver I need one by one and see which is causing my computer to not boot.

EDIT 2: I've installed all the drivers I need (Broadcom and Nvidia) and my MacBook boots fine. Now I'm not sure what the problem is and I can't check because I reinstalled Ubuntu. Also when I boot the two lines that start with "mtd device" don't appear anymore, but I thought those errors don't cause the computer to not boot as stated [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622). Does anyone know what the problem was? I think it has something to do with installing updates during the installation process or the other error messages.

Comment: If your mac model appears in [this](https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT208862) list, that means your Mac has a T2 chip which Ubuntu, or any kind of Linux distro, won't boot up because of the T2 chip. If you really want to have ubuntu on your T2 mac, then there is a wonderful community that has managed to patch this. This is their [site](https://t2linux.org) and their [discord server](https://discord.gg/y2tmHTuEv4)

Comment: If you do not have a T2 mac, then I will try my best to assist you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My MacBook is one from 2012 so no t2 chip, I should have put that in the post 

Comment: Thats odd... i had the 13 inch model and it had no issues. You could try [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu) and update me if it boots.

Comment: If not try [this](https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/)...Try reinstalling the drivers... Try checking for badblocks([howto-article](https://www.tecmint.com/check-linux-hard-disk-bad-sectors-bad-blocks/) )... Last resort would be to replace the hard drive since it is a old hard drive... and the hard drives with these things at this age would barely usable(very slow).

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm going to get some sleep and try these tomorrow morning.

Comment: Any update? Is the problem fixed?